# Getting [next-auth][warn][EXPERIMENTAL_API] when call await getServerSession(req)

Tags: node.js, next-auth

Here is my code that is executed when want to communicate with the nodejs

```
app.use(
  '/',
  cors<cors.CorsRequest>({
    origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
    credentials: true,
  }),
  // 50mb is the limit that `startStandaloneServer` uses, but you may configure this to suit your needs
  bodyParser.json({ limit: '50mb' }),
  // expressMiddleware accepts the same arguments:
  // an Apollo Server instance and optional configuration options
  expressMiddleware(server, {
    context: async ({ req }) => {
      const session = await getServerSession(req);
      console.log("API SESSION: ", req.headers.cookie.match('(session-token)'));
      
      // token: req.headers.token,
      return {}
    },
  }),
);
```

But, I am getting the following error.

```
[next-auth][warn][EXPERIMENTAL_API]
`getServerSession` is used in a React Server Component.
https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/nextjs#getServerSession}
https://next-auth.js.org/warnings#EXPERIMENTAL_API
```

I have also used **getSession()** but that did not work either.

Answer (score 8):

getServerSession is still in work (previous name was unstable_getServerSession, but is still in test...).
The warning shown may disappear when stable version of next-auth will be released with full support of Next13. It is not an error, so so far you can simply ignore it.

getSession works in client component and getServerSession in server Components.